# It is possible in cursor-based pagination to get the prev and next cursor in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Let's see, I'm making a mess with the cursor pagination, based on an `Id` in my case `ULID`, I want to return an array with the `results, next_cursor and prev_cursor`.

To obtain the `NextCursor` is very easy, I only have to add one more to the `Limit`, that is to say, if I have a limit of 10, I request 11 records and if I get 11 records then the `NextCursor` is the result 11. But for the `PrevCursor` the only thing I can think of is to do an additional Query to the one I am already doing. Example:

```
$limit = 10;

$result = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id <= $cursor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit+1'

$results    = array_slice($result, 0, $limit);
$nextCursor = array_slice($result, $limit, 1);
```

And now to get the Prev Cursor, I do as I said before an additional query

```
$prevCursor = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id > $cursor ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1'
```

That way my API can return the following array to the frontend

```
return [
  'data'        => $results,
  'next_cursor' => $nextCursor,
  'prev_cursor' => $prevCursor
];
```

Now I rephrase the same question again, is there any way to do this without having to do additional Mysql query to get the `Prev Cursor`, I mean in a same Query or in some other way, I don't know, it's the first time I do this, and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Shall we assume that `$cursor` is  a "next" or "previous" cursor value, except for possibly the initial query?

Comment: I've spotted an inconsistency in `$prevCursor` calculation: next cursor is `$limit` behind to given `id`, and prev cursor is only one row ahead. Am I right that previous cursor should be page ahead instead?

Comment: @Booboo Good question. In my example, I am assuming it is a Next Cursor,

Answer (score 3):

Indexing column allows you to quickly find specific row by its ULID and scan nearest rows forward and backward, but obviously, scanning forward and backward internally are two different operations, so if you insist on having the result of the both, you are doomed to perform two different operations.

There's some SQL syntactic sugar to help you hide those two internally executed operations inside one query, but first let me clarify around your objective a little.

**What you are trying to build here is actually a window, not a page.**

Pagination is when you have an ordered list of rows split over in pages of some size and user references an index of a page which she wants to browse. E.g. page #0, page #1, ... etc. Last page might have less items than a page size, and also if the total number of rows is less than a page, then first page and last page would be the same page and it's OK.

`LIMIT` and `OFFSET` operators are here to support that use case. A link to previous page is simply `min(0,current_page-1)` and a link to next page is `min(max_pages,current_page+1)`.

On the opposite side, windowing is when you have an ordered list of rows, and when user references some specific row by its ULID, you fetch him a few rows behind and/or after queried row. It's like `grep -C 10` in bash.

You can emulate window using sub-selects and `UNION`.

```
$limit = 10;
// Fetch a limit+1 of results after and including id AND
// a limit of results before id
$result = 'SELECT * FROM (
   (
     SELECT * from Table 
     WHERE  id >= $cursor ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit+1
   ) UNION (
     SELECT * from Table  
     WHERE id < $cursor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit
   )
) TableAlias ORDER by id;'

// as we actually fetching some rows before cursor
// we should find its position in the result set ...
$cursor_index = array_search($cursor, array_column($result, 'id'));
// ... and throw away the rest rows
$results      = array_slice($result, $cursor_index, $limit);

// here cursors are always first and last items of the result set
$prevCursor   = array_slice($result, 0, 1)['id'];
$nextCursor   = array_slice($result, -1, 1)['id'];

return [
  'data' => $results,
  'prev_cursor' => $prevCursor,
  'next_cursor' => $nextCursor
];
```

Since MySQL 8.0 you have a whole set of windowing functions, for your case, `LEAD()` and `LAG()` can help you move away all cursor calculations and slicing to your MySQL server.

```
$limit = 10;

// Wrap same query as above into sub-select, because LAG/LEAD work after WHERE, so we still need UNION to fetch previous cursor

$result = '
WITH 
 tab1 AS (SELECT * FROM Table where id >= $cursor ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit+1),
 tab2 AS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id < $cursor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit),
 tab3 AS (SELECT * FROM tab1 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * FROM tab2 ORDER BY id),
 tab4 AS (SELECT 
           *,
           LAG(id, 4) OVER (order by id) as prevcursor, 
           LEAD(id, 4) OVER (order by id) as nextcursor
          FROM tab3)
 
SELECT * FROM tab4
WHERE id >= $cursor LIMIT $limit'

// here calculated cursor ids are always on first row of result set
$prevCursor   = $result[0]['prevcursor'];
$nextCursor   = $result[0]['nextcursor'];

// (optionally) strip unwanted columns from result
$results      = array_map(function ($a) { return array_diff_key($a, array_flip(array('prevcursor', 'nextcursor'))); }, $result);

return [
  'data' => $results,
  'prev_cursor' => $prevCursor,
  'next_cursor' => $nextCursor
];
```

That should work well if you don't ever delete rows.

**Now, consider following. Both pagination and windowing do not work well with unstable lists.**

E.g. if new rows are sequentially adding to the end of the set, then the last page is constantly moving forward. So when one user is opening 'last' page and sees, say, three items there, another user might add another bunch of items and his view of what 'last' page would be different.

What's worse is that if your table usage allows deleting rows, the whole set of pages after and including the page where deleted row was is now rearranged. This leads to very nasty user experience when user is clicking 'next' page and accidentally skips some items, or is clicking 'previous' and sees some of the items he has already seen before.

To overcome those deficiencies you might want to redesign your API such that querying 'previous' page and 'next' page be semantically clearly different from querying 'current' page.

That is, you would need three API endpoints:

1. query a row by ULID (and a set of up to N rows after it) - initial user entry point from, e.g. search or catalog tree.
2. query a set of N rows **before** specific ULID. You pass ULID of the first row in the window user is currently looking at. If there are no rows before given one, result set is empty, you might either display a notification message to user or silently redirect them to first endpoint.
3. query a set of N rows **after** specific ULID. You pass ULID of the last row in the window user is currently looking at. If there are no rows after given one, result set is empty, you might either display a notification message to user or silently redirect them back.

If you design your API that way, you would have following benefits:

- all three API implemented by only simple ORDER and LIMIT
- no need in second query neither explicit nor implicit
- your next/previous window results would not ever have any misses or duplicates comparing to previously seen windows.

The only drawback here is that original row user is referring to can be deleted as well. To overcome this, you might want to add a boolean `deleted` flag to your table schema and set it to false instead of actual row deletion.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I have to say that I had seen many tutorials on pagination based on cursor. None talked about if they did any magic or actually did additional Query to get the previous one. I have also seen another way is that the client had already gone through that page and could already send the API the previous Cursor. But I don't like this, the idea is to send a cursor either to have the next or the previous ones, and when the server responds it gives all updated information.

Answer (score 1):

After reading @shomeax 's comment and thinking a little more I can suggest to encode cursor in base-64 and make it to contain prev cursor additionally. For example:

```
[$prevCursor, $curCursor] = explode(':', base64_decode($request['cursor']));
$limit = 10;
$prevPlusCurPagesLimit = $limit * 2;
$ulids = 'SELECT ulid FROM Table WHERE ulid <= $prevCursor ORDER BY ulid DESC LIMIT $prevPlusCurPagesLimit+1';

$resultUlids = array_slice($ulids, $limit, $limit);
$nextCursor = array_slice($ulids, $prevPlusCurPagesLimit, 1);
$prevPrevCursor = reset($ulids);

$response = [
    'data' => $resultUlids,
    'prevCursor' => base64_encode("$curCursor:$nextCursor"),
    'nextCursor' => base64_encode("$prevPrevCursor:$prevCursor"),
];
```

I didn't try such approach myself but it is partially based on this article https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack/ and looks like working

Comment: But note, that this approach implies querying twice as much records, instead of making one more query. So you should consider possible drawbacks.

Comment: The idea is good, I had seen that tutorial, but I couldn't figure out if for the Prev Cursor they did an additional query or some kind of magic, I should have put it in the question.

Comment: Actually, I only took an idea to encode cursors from that article. The idea to get prev-prev-cursor each time and pass it around is mine )

Comment: The problem here is that if I attack the API with specific or random ULID to get the next cursor, but I would also like to know if there is a previous Cursor, this would not work, since the client does not really need to know if there is a previous cursor, and wants to know beforehand, then I will need to apply an additional Query. Although most of the bases are going to know because it has somehow reached that cursor in some way.

Comment: you are right, client cannot know prevCursor beforehand. But it really doesn't need. If client wants to start from random ULID, it can pass empty prevCursor. You could edit my pseudo-code a little, adding handling of such situations. The inevitable rule for clients would be like "if you (client) don't know prev cursor, me (sever) do not know it too"), i.e. if prevCursor is empty in request, it will be empty in response.

Comment: so the only limitation is that client cannot paginate back from random ULID.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this...

You fetch the 5 rows for the current page.  Then the "previous" page ends before the first id on this page and the "next" page starts after the last id on the current page.

Example:  The current page contains ids 65, 67, 71, 82, 91.  This finds the 5 rows for the previous page:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE id < 65
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```

(They will be in reverse order, but that is easy to fix.)  For the "next" page (in proper order):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE id > 91
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 5;
```

As another tip:  fetching an extra row (6 instead of 5), lets you cheaply discover whether you are at the "end", thereby being able to suppress the [Next] or [Prev] button.

More: [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Granted, this technique does not deliver the 5 rows for the next/previous page, but do you really need that?  Since the Selects should be quite efficient, I don't necessarily see a drawback of doing more than one Select *or* combining selects with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to request more, only use < and > rather than <= and >=.
Then you can use the last id in $results for next and the first id for previous.

Comment: Yeah but what if you're on the first page? Then you display a previous cursor without actually having a previous page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. the "cursor" is the ID from which the next portion starts
2. and IDs are sequential and without gaps,
3. and limit is not changed from one query to another

you could get the prev cursor by substracting/adding (depending on sorting) $limit from/to current cursor: `$prevCursor = $results[0]['id'] - $limit`

And if the ID column has gaps, I suppose there is no reasonable way to implement ability to get prev cursor without additional query. You could only turn it into sub-query or use UNION, but this does not make a big difference.

Comment: Topic starter is using ULID, not the integer ids, so that math does not apply here

https://github.com/ulid/spec

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for omitting such an important detail )

Answer (score 0):

I am going to delete my previous answer, despite its upvote, because it is clearly the wrong approach.

**Update**

Given that you are retrieving on a column, `id`, that is presumably unique and indexed, then when a "page" of N rows is returned (where N is 10), you need to pass up either the id of the first row (the one with the greater value since we are sorting by descending `id`) or the last row as query parameter `lastId` along with a direction flag parameter `directionFlag` that is either `F` for forward or `B` for backward to give the direction of "paging." It should then be possible to directly seek to the correct rows as follows (I am assuming that we are using PDO for MySql Access):

```php
define(PAGE_SIZE, 10);

$limit = PAGE_SIZE;

// lastId parameter specified? It will not be present on the initial request:
if (isset($_REQUEST('lastId')) {
    $lastId = $_REQUEST['lastId'];
    $direction = $_REQUEST['direction']; 'F'orward or 'B'ackward
    if ($direction == 'F') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC where id < :id LIMIT $limit";
    }
    else {
        // paging backward:
        $sql = "SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id ASC where id > :id LIMIT $limit) sq ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
    $params = [':id' => $lastId];
}
else {
    // this is the initial request: 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
    $params = [];
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// The id from $rows[0] will be passed back as lastId with direction flag 'B' for paging backward
// And the id from $rows[PAGE_SIZE-1] will be passed back as lastId with direction flag 'F' for paging forward
```